# How to render a dropdown based on an API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, outlook-addin, office-addins

I was wondering how to render a dropdown after populating it with an API call, in an Outlook Add-in. It does not show on the screen for me.

Basic example:

```
const App () => {
    let contactDropdown = <></>;

    (async () => {
        await Office.onReady();

        const contacts = await getContacts();
        contactDropdown = buildDropdown(contacts);
    })();

    const buildDropdown = (contacts) => {
        //e.g.:
        // contacts = [
        //     { value: 1, text: "Tim" },
        //     { value: 2, text: "Fred" }
        // ];

        return (
            <div>
                <label>Choose a Contact</label>
                <select>
                    {contacts.map((option) => (
                        <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                          {option.text}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                </select>
            </div>
          );
    };

    return (
        <div>
          {contactDropdown}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Do I need to use `useEffect` and state to load the data first? I tried this but it isn't working.

```
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    setContacts(getContacts());
  }, []);

  const getContacts = async () => {
    //api call here
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't have to wait for the data to be fetched to define the dropdown component.

Secondly, in your attempt to use state, you stored the promise inside state, not the actual result.

Proof of concept:

```js
const ContactsDropdown = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    getContacts()
      .catch((err) => (console.error(err), []))
      .then((r) => {
        setLoading(false)
        setContacts(r) // or r.data!? (depends on server response)
      })
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      {loading && <div>loading contacts...</div>}
      {!loading && !contacts.length && <div>no contacts loaded!</div>}
      {!loading && contacts.length && (
        <>
          <label>Choose a Contact</label>
          <select>
            {contacts.map(({ value, text }) => (
              <option key={value} value={value}>
                {text}
              </option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

For brevity, the above component does the fetching of data, but that might not be ideal.

Might make more sense to lift that state up into the parent component and pass the contacts down to the dropdown, as a prop, once they've been fetched.

Here's how that might look like (still bare-bones, but demonstrates the principle):

```js
const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React
const ContactsDropdown = ({ contacts, ...props }) => (
  <select {...props}>
    <option>-- Select a contact --</option>
    {contacts.map(({ id, name }) => (
      <option key={id} value={id}>
        {name}
      </option>
    ))}
  </select>
)
const App = () => {
  const [
    [contacts, setContacts],
    [selected, setSelected],
    [loading, setLoading]
  ] = [[], null, false].map(useState)
  useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(true)
    // delay by a second, to demo loading..
    setTimeout(() => {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(setContacts)
        .then(() => setLoading(false))
    }, 1e3)
  }, [])
  const cdProps = {
    contacts,
    value: (selected && selected.id) || '',
    onChange: ({ target: { value } }) =>
      setSelected(contacts.find(({ id }) => id === +value) || null)
  }
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {loading && <div>contacts loading...</div>}
      {!loading && !contacts.length && <div>no contacts!</div>}
      {!loading && contacts.length && <ContactsDropdown {...cdProps} />}
      <pre>{JSON.stringify({ selected }, null, 2)}</pre>
    </Fragment>
  )
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(root).render(<App />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```